# How can I modify part of a url when using Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

How can I automatically increment the day in this URL?

```
reportDate = "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/API/setReportDate.aspx?bdate=06/25/2015&edate=06/23/2015&authcode=secretAuthcode"
setReportDate = requests.get(reportDate)
```

Comment: Downvoting for reason "this question does not show any research effort". Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` doesn't have any URL editing functionality. You could parse the URL manually with `urlparse`, splitting up the query params, getting the date and incrementing it with `datetime`, then rebuild the string yourself to pass it back to requests.